# PostgreSQL - Aggregate values in JSON object without specifying keys

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to get a sum of values in a JSON array grouped by a `shop_id` and key, and get the output in the same format.

So, with an array like this:

```
[
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 2, "skateboard": 5},
        shop_id: 6321
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 1, "skateboard": 3},
        shop_id: 6243
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 3, "skateboard": 4},
        shop_id: 6243
    }
]
```

The output should look like:

```
[
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 2, "skateboard": 5},
        shop_id: 6321
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 4, "skateboard": 7},
        shop_id: 6243
    }
]
```

The JSON input will always be uniform. I can get it to work if I use `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` and `JSON_AGG` but I don't want to specify what keys to use while building JSON because the real data will probably hold around 20 different keys, so I am looking for a cleaner solution.

```
SELECT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('bicycle', SUM((sales::json ->> 'bicycle')::int),
                         'skateboard', SUM((sales::json ->> 'skateboard')::int)
           ) AS sales,
       shop_id
FROM (SELECT val ->> 'sales' AS sales, val ->> 'shop_id' AS shop_id
      FROM (SELECT UNNEST($1)::jsonb AS val) core) outercore
GROUP BY shop_id;
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: 11.9 but there are plans to upgrade to 13.2 later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract all items to key/value pairs, then you can aggregate them back into a single JSON:

```
select jsonb_agg(s)
from (
  select shop_id, 
         jsonb_object_agg(typ, value) as sales
  from (       
    select (t.item ->> 'shop_id')::int as shop_id,
           s.typ, 
           sum(value::int) as value
    from your_table yt --<< this is where the json column comes from
      cross join jsonb_array_elements(yt.val) as t(item)
      cross join jsonb_each(t.item -> 'sales') as s(typ, value)
    group by id, shop_id, typ 
  ) x
  group by id, shop_id  
) s  
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f3de038a8d72d0802af2700e4750f953)